# Initial MySQL 5.7 installation on RHEL Instance Fails to Start

Tags: mysql, redhat-enterprise-linux

I did a standard MySQL install with Chef on an AMI on AWS. Here's the recipe:

```
mysql_service 'default' do
  bind_address '0.0.0.0'
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'hunter2'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql_config 'default' do
  source 'mysite.cnf.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[default]'
  action :create
end
```

After correcting some self-inflicted wounds (didn't update Yum before I installed) the recipe now runs correctly up to a point. At the last step, where MySQL is supposed to start, it fails. It appears to be a Chef error, as I *can* execute the following outside of Chef:

```
 sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Here's the output of this `sudo systemctl status mysql-default.service -l`:

```
[ec2-user@ip-250-250-250-250 ~]$ sudo systemctl status mysql-default.service -l
mysql-default.service - mysql_service[mysql-default]
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql-default.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2014-12-21 17:36:01 EST; 21min ago
  Process: 26423 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-default-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26422 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26422 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 21 17:36:00 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal mysqld_safe[26422]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 542: /var/lib/mysql-default/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied
Dec 21 17:36:00 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal mysqld_safe[26422]: awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=2) warning: error writing standard output (Broken pipe)
Dec 21 17:36:00 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal mysqld_safe[26422]: 141221 17:36:00 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql-default/error.log'.
Dec 21 17:36:00 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal mysqld_safe[26422]: 141221 17:36:00 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql-default
Dec 21 17:36:00 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal mysqld_safe[26422]: 141221 17:36:00 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysql-default/mysqld.pid ended
Dec 21 17:36:01 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: mysql-default.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 21 17:36:01 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start mysql_service[mysql-default].
Dec 21 17:36:01 ip-250-250-250-250.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysql-default.service entered failed state.
```

Seems pretty clear it's some kind of permissions issue, on /var/lib/mysql-default, but I'm running it as `sudo` so I'm not sure what the issue would be. Here's the directory output:

```
[...]
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql   mysql      6 Sep 18 10:07 mysql
drwxr-x---.  4 mysql   mysql   4096 Dec 21 17:36 mysql-default
[...]
```

The `$DATADIR` is `/var/lib/mysql-default`. The relevant lines in `/usr/bin/mysql_safe` are:

```
safe_pid="$DATADIR/mysqld_safe.pid"

[ ... bunch of error checking ...]

# Insert pid properly into the pid file.
ps -e | grep  [m]ysqld_safe | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n 1p > $safe_pid
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 542: /var/lib/mysql-default/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied

You're right,
the process fails because it cannot write to the pid file.

Although you're running the startup script with `sudo`,
the server process is most probably started with the user `mysql`.
In the default configuration there should be a line like this in `mysqld_safe`:

> user='mysql'

Check the owner and permissions of `/var/lib/mysql-default` with:

```
ls -ld /var/lib/mysql-default
```

Normally it should be owned by the same user as in the config file, with permission 755.

Comment: Interesting - good point. Here's that output:

    [ec2-user@ip-250-250-250-250 ~]$ ls -ld /var/lib/mysql-default
drwxr-x---. 4 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 21 18:24 /var/lib/mysql-default

Comment: That looks correct. Try this: become the `mysql` user with `sudo su - mysql` and try to create a file in that directory. Can it?